# Extracting String from dataframe in Python

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe which includes "genres column" and it structure is like :

```
0    [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam..."
1    [{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "..."
2    [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam..."
3    [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 80, "nam..."
4    [{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "nam..."
Name: genres, dtype: object
```

I just wanna extract the genres like "Action" "Adventure" etc.

I have used different method but none of them achieved.

```
d2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\nxx\PycharmProjects\tmdb_5000_movies.csv")
d2=pd.DataFrame(d2)
d2["genres"] = re.search(" (.?)}",d2["genres"]).group(1,2)
```

When execute above code, i get following error.

```
Name: genres, dtype: object
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I tried to convert column to str but it did not work.

I tried following as well.

```
x=["Action","Crime","Horror","Drama","Comedy","Romance","Thriller","Documentary","Family","Adventure","Animation" "Science Fiction","Mystery","Fantasy","War","History","Music"]


d2["genres"] = d2["genres"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x["Action"] for i in x)) print(d2["genres"]) 
d2["genres"] = d2["genres"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x["Action"] for i in x)) TypeError: string indices must be integers –
```

Comment: `d2=pd.DataFrame(d2)` isn't necessary. You get your source already wrapped up as a dataframe when you use `pd.read_csv()`. It will be helpful if you can include a sample data in a code block in your question above - `print(d2)`

Comment: Thanks for illustrator answer. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract the name from the list

**Use:**

```
d2 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\nxx\PycharmProjects\tmdb_5000_movies.csv")
d2["genres"] = d2["genres"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(i["name"] for i in x))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.

However; I get following error for following code.


x =["Action","Crime","Horror","Drama","Comedy","Romance","Thriller","Documentary","Family","Adventure","Animation"
                "Science Fiction","Mystery","Fantasy","War","History","Music"]
d2["genres"] = d2["genres"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x["Action"] for i in x))
print(d2["genres"])

d2["genres"] = d2["genres"].apply(lambda x: ", ".join(x["Action"] for i in x))
TypeError: string indices must be integers